# How to visit multiple links with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, staleelementreferenceexception

i'm trying to visit multiple links from one page, and then go back to the same page.

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a')
    
for link in links:
     link.click() # visit page
     # scrape page 
     driver.back() # get back to previous page, and click the next link in next iteration
```

The code says it all

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code should work, however you might want to add a sleep in between certain actions, it makes a difference when scraping.

```
import time
```

and then add `time.sleep(seconds)` where it matters.

Comment: Ahh thank you for the correction, I meant "from time import sleep"

I guess I'm the one who needs sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

By navigating to another page all collected by selenium web elements (they are actually references to a physical web elements) become no more valid since the web page is re-built when you open it again.
To make your code working you need to collect the links list again each time.
This should work:

```py
import time
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a')
    
for i in range(len(links)):
    links[i].click() # visit page
    # scrape page 
    driver.back() # get back to previous page, and click the next link in next iteration 
    time.sleep(1) # add a delay to make the main page loaded
    links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a') # collect the links again on the main page
```

Also make sure all the `a` elements on that page are relevant links. Since this may not be correct